# Using Union tool without optional overlay layer

Tags: qgis-3, geoprocessing, union

In QGIS 3.10.3, I'm trying to figure out how to use the Union tool without the optional overlay layer.

When I go to `"Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Union..."` and bring up the tool, the description says the overlay layer is optional, but the field is already filled in and I can't for the life of me figure out how to clear the field and run the tool without the overlay layer.

Answer (score 2):

If you scroll the overlay layer dropdown menu you can choose an empty value (in first position). Result will be an union between self intersections of the source layer entities.